# How to return the response Body of the server response instead of Nginx defaulte Error page

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, nginx-location

Here is my nginx conf file, I want to where `/test` is what the route is, where I want to test the authentication first, then proceed.
But when /auth/ responds with some 401 error code and a json body, it just responds back with 401 and default nginx error page, But I still want the error response body to be redirected. Any suggestions?

```
events {
    worker_connections 1000;
}

http {
    server {
        listen 80;
        location /auth/ {
          proxy_pass http://app:5000/give_401;
        }

        location /test {
            auth_request /auth/;
            proxy_pass http://app:5000/ok;

        }
    }
 }
```